NeoVim Groovylsp
Is groovylsp available on Windows? I use with mason and mason-lspconfig and groovyls, but I don't get autocompletion.

What happens when you launch the LSP server from the command line console (cmd)?

As phrased, this question is not on-topic: whether or not groovylsp is available on windows has nothing to do with Vi/Vim/neovim
